# How to output raster that contains band numbers of pixelwise maximum values?

Tags: qgis, r

I have got a ndvi_2015.tif with 12 bands of monthly ndvi values (band 1 = January, band 2 = February etc.), which I used to create a summary raster layer using the max() function in R. Now I want to know which month the the maximum occurred in. How do I go about preferably using R?

Comment: use `r which.max(r)` to get a single layer raster with the layer index of the maximum value

Comment: Good comment @mdsumner, but it would make a better answer;)